# Union of const/non-const Object Pointers

Tags: c++, constants

Consider the sample code below:

```
class A
{
public:

    A() : n(0) {}

    int n;
};

class B
{
public:

    B(A* a) : mA(a) { }
    B(const A* a) : mConstA(a) { }

    union {
        A* mA;
        const A* mConstA;
    };
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    B b1(&a);
    B b2(const_cast<const A*>(&a));

    return 0;
}
```

At construction, `b1` would have a mutable pointer to `a`, while `b2` would have an immutable pointer to `a`. In this scenario, `b1.mA` equals `b2.mConstA`, and `b1.mConstA` equals `b2.mA`.

Are these equalities always true when you have a union of `const` and non-`const` object pointers?

Similarly, the code below compiles/runs fine:

```
int main()
{
    const A a;
    B b(&a);
    b.mA->n = 3; // Blasphemy!!!

    return 0;
}
```

But is it guaranteed for `b.mA` to always be equal to `b.mConstA`?

Comment: Note that those are not *const/non-const variables*, but rather non-const pointers to *const/non-const objects*.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas You're right. Fixed. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are these equalities always true when you have a union of const and non-const members?

Yes, both pointers will refer to the same object in the same address. The bits in memory will be the same.

> But is it guaranteed for b.mA to always be equal to b.mConstA?

Yes, their values will be the same, but that does not mean that you can really *use it*. This is equivalent to using `const_cast`, you will get a non-const pointer to the object, but if the object is really `const`, using that pointer to modify the object is undefined behavior.