# Using smart pointers to keep track of data members that may be deleted

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, datamember

I have two classes `A` and `B`. I compute a `B` deterministically from an `A`. For each `A`, I want to keep track of the `B` with `my_B` for as long as it exists. Once the `B` is destructed, I want the `my_B` to be changed to something like `nullptr`.

```
class A{
// stuff
public:
    B ComputeB(){
        if (my_B is null){
            B result = B(A);
            my_B = B; // some kind of reference
            return B(A);
        } 
        else {
            return my_B;
        }
    }
    
    ~A(){  /* Do I need a destructor? */ }
private:
    WhatTypeHere my_B;
}
```

When `B` is destructed, what will cause `my_B` to refer to `nullptr` (or the equivalent for `WhatTypeHere`)?

Comment: What research did you do about smart pointers, and what particular part of them is not clear to you?

Comment: @t.niese the very last line is my question. If someone can answer that question with smart pointers, then my question is answered. Though I also tried to keep the question open to non-smart pointer solutions. "When B is destructed, what will cause ```my_B``` to refer to ```nullptr``` (or the equivalent for ```WhatTypeHere```)?"

Comment: [When is std::weak_ptr useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030650/when-is-stdweak-ptr-useful)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return a std::shared_ptr from ComputeB(), and make my_B a std::weak_ptr. Something like this:

```
std::shared_ptr<B> ComputeB() {
    if (my_B.expired()) {
        auto result = std::make_shared<B>(*this);
        my_B = result;
        return result;
    } else {
        return std::shared_ptr<B>(my_B);
    }
}

private:
std::weak_ptr<B> my_B;
```

The idea is that any caller of ComputeB becomes the partial owner of the B instance, which means that it will only be destroyed when all shared_ptrs to it are destroyed. The purpose of the weak_ptr is to point to the B instance without owning it, so the lifetime isn't tied to the A instance at all

Comment: This makes sense. The internals of how ```weak_ptr``` works vs. how it could work is weird to me. I guess  this wouldn't work if ```ComputeB``` returned a ```B``` (to be stored on the stack) so that when the ```B``` was deleted when it left scope, the ```weak_ptr``` expires?

Comment: No, weak_ptr is specifically for use with shared_ptrs, because it's able to use shared_ptr's internal reference count to see if the object is destroyed or not

Comment: It seems to me like you can't return a regular B instance here though, because if you did you would have to create a new one every time the function was called and you would end up overwriting my_B with a pointer to the latest instance every time

Comment: Note that the use of `expired` results with code that is not thread safe. It may happen that `my_B` expires right after it passed the check - thus ComputeB would return nullptr. It would be better to use `my_B.lock()` if it is null create, otherwise return it.

Comment: @AmirKirsh "It would be better to use ```my_B.lock()``` if it null create, otherwise return it." Your phrasing here is a little confusing, if you could clarify.

Answer (score 4):

### Using shared_ptr and weak_ptr

In order to keep your `B` object alive in `A` as long as it is still in use, you should have a data member in `A` of type `std::weak_ptr<B>` this will allow to access the created `B` object, as long as it is alive.

The return value from `computeB` would be `std::shared_ptr<B>` that would be either acquired from the `std::weak_ptr<B>` member or created, if the latter is holding `nullptr`.

---

### Thread safety

The decision whether to *create* or *acquire* the existing `B` shall be thread-safe. For this you shall try to fetch the actual `B` held by the `weak_ptr` by using the `lock()` method, then only if the return value is `nullptr` create a new one.

---

The code would look like this:

```
class A {
    // stuff
public:
    std::shared_ptr<B> ComputeB() {
        std::shared_ptr<B> shared_b = my_B.lock();
        if (!shared_b){
            shared_b = std::make_shared<B>(*this);
            my_B = shared_b;
        } 
        return shared_b;
    }
    // no need for a destructor, unless "stuff" needs one
    // ~A(){} 
private:
    std::weak_ptr<B> my_B;
};
```

---

### Copy and assignment

The behavior of above class in copying and assignment is problematic, as the default copy constructor and default assignment operator would perform member-wise copy/assignment, which may result with two different `A`'s holding a `weak_ptr` to the same `B`. Most probably this is not what you want, especially not if `A` is mutable (i.e. can change its inner values).

To present suggested code for copy and assignment, let's assume `A` holds an int member. The code would then look like this:

```
class A {
    int i;
public:
    A(int i1): i(i1) {}
    void set(int i1) { i = i1; }
    std::shared_ptr<B> ComputeB() {
        std::shared_ptr<B> shared_b = my_B.lock();
        if (!shared_b){
            shared_b = std::make_shared<B>(*this);
            my_B = shared_b;
        } 
        return shared_b;
    }
    A(const A& a): i(a.i) {}
    A& operator=(const A& a) { i = a.i; return *this; }
    ~A() {}
private:
    std::weak_ptr<B> my_B;
};
```

---

### Preserving constness

In the code above, the call to `ComputeB()` cannot be done on a `const A` object. If we want to support that we need to have a const version of this function. For matter of semantics I prefer renaming this method (both the *const* and *non-const* versions) to `getB`.

To present suggested code that adds the option for calling `getB` on a `const A` object we need to present also an example of class `B` which is able to hold either a *const* or *non-const* reference to `A`. The code would then look like this:

```
class A {
    int i;
    // to prevent code duplication for the const and non-const versions
    template<typename AType>
    static auto getB(AType&& a) {
        std::shared_ptr<B> shared_b = a.my_B.lock();
        if (!shared_b){
            shared_b = std::make_shared<B>(std::forward<AType>(a));
            a.my_B = shared_b;
        } 
        return shared_b;
    }
public:
    A(int i1): i(i1) {}
    void set(int i1) { i = i1; }
    std::shared_ptr<B> getB() {
        return getB(*this);
    }
    std::shared_ptr<const B> getB() const {
        return getB(*this);
    }
    A(const A& a): i(a.i) {}
    A& operator=(const A& a) { i = a.i; return *this; }
    ~A() {}
private:
    mutable std::weak_ptr<B> my_B;
};
```

And for B:

```
class B {
    union Owner {
        A* const ptr;
        const A* const const_ptr;
        Owner(A& a): ptr(&a) {}
        Owner(const A& a): const_ptr(&a) {}
    } owner;
public:
    B(A& a): owner(a) {}
    B(const A& a): owner(a) {}
    const A& getOwner() const {
        return *owner.const_ptr;
    }
    A& getOwner() {
        return *owner.ptr;
    }
};
```

On the use of `union` to manage *const* and *non-const* versions of the same pointer, see:

- [Union of const/non-const Object Pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18063233/union-of-const-non-const-object-pointers)
- [Is const-casting via a union undefined behaviour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8836418/is-const-casting-via-a-union-undefined-behaviour)

Working example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f696dfcf85890977

---

### Private creation token

The code above allows anybody to create objects of `B` which may lead to undesired possibilities, like creating a non-const `B` object via the constructor that gets `const A& a`, resulting with a potential casting from const to non-const when calling `getOwner()`.

A good solution might be to block the creation of `B` and allow it only from class `A`. Since the creation is done via `make_shared` putting `B`'s constructors in the `private` section of `B` with a `friend` declaration for `A` wouldn't help, it is not `A` that is calling `new B` it is `make_shared`. So we go for a private token approach as in the following code:

```
class A {    
    int i;
    // only authorized entities can create B
    class B_PrivateCreationToken {};    
    friend class B;

    template<typename AType>
    static auto getB(AType&& a) {
        std::shared_ptr<B> shared_b = a.my_B.lock();
        if (!shared_b){
            shared_b = std::make_shared<B> (
                  std::forward<AType>(a),
                  B_PrivateCreationToken{} );
            a.my_B = shared_b;
        } 
        return shared_b;
    }
public:

    // public part as in above version...

private:
    mutable std::weak_ptr<B> my_B;
};
```

And for B:

```
class B {
    union Owner {
        A* const ptr;
        const A* const const_ptr;
        Owner(A& a): ptr(&a) {}
        Owner(const A& a): const_ptr(&a) {}
    } owner;
public:
    B(A& a, A::B_PrivateCreationToken): owner(a) {}
    B(const A& a, A::B_PrivateCreationToken): owner(a) {}

    // getOwner methods as in above version...

};
```

Code: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f656a3992d666e1e